# How can I replace a tag without disturbing the content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am just wanted to remove an html tag (both opening and closing) without disturbing the content.

**For example, given this markup...**

```
var temp =
<span id="myspan1">
<span id="myspan2" class="new">
hello world !</span>
</span>
```

**I want to get to this...**

```
var newcontent = 
<span id="mySpan1">
    hello world !
</span>
```

Please help me resolve with this in jquery.

Comment: Get innerHTML of `#myspan2` and assign it to `#myspan1`?

Comment: Did you really mean to change the `id` of `myspan1` to `mySpan1`?

Answer (score 7):

I think jQuery's got an [`unwrap`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/). Since `unwrap` removes the parent, we need to get the contents of `#myspan2` to make `#myspan2` the parent to be removed, [ending up with `#myspan1` being the parent](http://jsfiddle.net/FVxHT/).

```
$('#myspan2').contents().unwrap();
```

To further clarify why `unwrap` is better than doing `html` is that when you do `.html()`, it only retrieves a string representation of the DOM descending from the current element. It does not fetch the handlers and data that come with those descendants. Thus, if you recreate the DOM with that HTML string, it does recreate the DOM properly but [does not anymore have the handlers and data](http://jsfiddle.net/hXne5/1/) that were attached to those descendants.

Comment: What s the difference between `unwrap` and other answers below ? Any advantage of using unwrap ?

Comment: @2-Stroker the `html` method returns a string, and you lose the events and data bound to the html you retrieved. Reconstructs the DOM using that string does return the structure but not the data or handlers. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hXne5/1/). That's why `unwrap` is better since it just moves around elements.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, as long as you have no other content in the `myspan1` span:

```
$("#myspan1").html($("#myspan2").html());
```

It replaces the content of the `myspan1` span with the contents of `myspan2`, effectively removing the tag. For the example given it works, but it would fail if you have other content inside `myspan1` besides `myspan2`.

Comment: I'd recommend avoiding going through markup for this, not least because event handlers would be lost.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
$('#myspan1').html($('#myspan2').html())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myspan1').html($('#myspan2').html());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var temp = '<span id="myspan1"><span id="myspan2" class="new">hello world !</span></span>';

var $t = $(temp);
$t.find('.new').contents().unwrap();
console.log($t[0].outerHTML)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to assign the content of a immediate child element to parent element, you can use this

```
$("#myspan2").parent().html($("#myspan2").html());
```